# How do wildcards in Java import work?

Tags: java, syntax, import

I've been noticing some unexpected results with my `import`s, and I'm hoping to understand what's really going on. I started with the following:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

and then found that `ArrayList` and `ListIterator` didn't work...so I added

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
```

and everything works perfectly.

I would have assumed that `java.util.*` would have also imported `ArrayList` and `ListIterator`. Why didn't it?

I've a tendency to be overly verbose with my class/method/variable names, and I didn't find anything in the rest of the program that was even *close* to a reserved word.

I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests why this would occur, and most of the discussion on Stack is about optimaztion using * vs. explicitly coded imports.

Anyone have any ideas what else I can look at to get an understanding of this behavior?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "didn't work"? Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I am not getting your problem

Comment: Create a minimal example where you can demonstrate your problem. Don't use your existing massive class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import java.util.*` **definitely** imports `java.util.ArrayList` and everything else in that package too. Note that there's no concept of sub-packages, so it wouldn't import anything from `java.util.x` or `java.util.y`, but that doesn't appear to be the case with your issue.

You must have some other problem wrong with your code if it's not working, the import statements definitely behave as you describe.

Comment: This answer is not technically correct. If there is another package with a wildcard import which also contains a class named `ArrayList`, then **neither** class is imported, and if you use the type `ArrayList` you'll get a compilation error due to the ambiguous name. You can try this in practice with `import java.awt.*; import java.util.*;` since both packages contain a type named `List`.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried in eclipse.

```
import java.util.*;
```

these both the classes no need import again.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
```

because wild card * means import all sub classes and packages (remember not package sub class)

if you import

```
import java.util.*;
```

i will import **java.util.jar** package but not jar subclasses
:)